# Не могу убрать значение цены "0"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]помогите кто в курсе, вот код в "вордпрессе",

```
  <?php 
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'curr_price', 10, 2 );

   function curr_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( $price <= 250 ) {
        $price = $price * 3;
    } elseif ( $price > 250 && $price <= 500 ) {
        $price = $price * 2;
    } elseif ( $price > 500 && $price <= 1000 ) {
        $price = $price * 1.8;
    } elseif ( $price > 1000 && $price <= 2500 ) {
        $price = $price * 1.5;
    } elseif ( $price > 2500 && $price<= 5000 ) {
        $price = $price * 1.3;
    } elseif ( $price > 5000 && $price <= 8000 ) {
        $price = $price * 1.2;
    } else {
       $price = $price * 1.1;
    }
    return $price;
    }
   ?>
```

Проблема в том что когда нет цены, этот фильтр возвращает "0.00 руб.", а мне нужно что бы выполнялся фильтр:

```
  function filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html($price, $_product) {
   if ($_product->get_price() == 0) return __('<span class="woocommerce- 
   Price-amount amount">Цену уточняйте</span>');
   return $price;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нашел решение (день не зря) кому интересно, работает 100%:
Спасибо за внимание!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'curr_price', 10, 2 );

function curr_price( $price, $product ) {
if ( $price <= 250 ) {
    $price = $price * 3;
} elseif ( $price > 250 && $price <= 500 ) {
    $price = $price * 2;
} elseif ( $price > 500 && $price <= 1000 ) {
    $price = $price * 1.8;
} elseif ( $price > 1000 && $price <= 2500 ) {
    $price = $price * 1.5;
} elseif ( $price > 2500 && $price<= 5000 ) {
    $price = $price * 1.3;
} elseif ( $price > 5000 && $price <= 8000 ) {
    $price = $price * 1.2;
} else {
   $price = $price * 1.1;
}
if ( $price == 0 ) {
  $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_empty_price_html', '', $this );
}
return $price;
}

function my_price_call($price, $product) {
if ($product->get_price() == 0)  return __( '<span class="price-call">Цена 
по 
запросу</span>' );
return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_price_call', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```js
function filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html($price, $_product) {
   if ($_product->get_price() == 0) {
   return __('<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">Цену уточняйте</span>');
   } else return $price;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```js
<?php 
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'curr_price', 10, 2 );

   function curr_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( $price <= 250 ) {
        $price = $price * 3;
    } elseif ( $price > 250 && $price <= 500 ) {
        $price = $price * 2;
    } elseif ( $price > 500 && $price <= 1000 ) {
        $price = $price * 1.8;
    } elseif ( $price > 1000 && $price <= 2500 ) {
        $price = $price * 1.5;
    } elseif ( $price > 2500 && $price<= 5000 ) {
        $price = $price * 1.3;
    } elseif ( $price > 5000 && $price <= 8000 ) {
        $price = $price * 1.2;
    } else {
       $price = $price * 1.1;
    }
    if ( $price == 0 ) {
      $price = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">Цену уточняйте</span>';
    }
    return $price;
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: не не помогло, все равно "0,00 руб".

Comment: вы уверены что этот фильтр срабатывает? Попробуйте заменить return __('<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">Цену уточняйте</span>');   на return 777; И посмотрите что возвращает

Comment: этот фильтр работает 100% : 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_empty_price_html', 
    10, 2 );

но когда подключаю этот, 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'curr_price', 10, 2 );
цена строится как мне надо но товары без цены с нулями

Comment: То есть, мой фильтр где-то рушит систему отображения, цены, не пойму где только.

Comment: обновил в ответе, смотрите

Comment: уже пробовал разные варианты реализации кода, в файлах плагинов (/price.php), все приводит к нулевой цене, по этому задал вопрос, что не так с этой ценой происходит когда я вставляю фильтр 'curr_price'?

Comment: не срабатывает только на нулевой цене?

Comment: когда поле цены пустое в карточке товара, но если туда поставить любое число, оно умножается согласно фильтру

Comment: еще раз обновил фильтр, попробуйте, если не получиться, то вместо $price = 'span ....' , напишите $price = 7777; И проверьте еще раз

Comment: :)) Я уже тоже так пробовал, цена 7,777.00 , то-есть цифры видит а буквы в скобках нет....

Comment: if ( $price == 0 ) {
      return "Цену уточняйте";
    } else  return $price;

Comment: тоже самое, ладно спасибо и на этом, пойду дальше искать истину.